# Finding trends in scatter plot with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have been working on a maths project and I thought I would create the graphs using matplotlib. I had created a scatterplot and was wondering if I could identify trends and outliers with it.

I have already looked through the matplotlib documentation and haven't found any answers

```
import matplotlib as plt

x = ['Harleen', 'Shami', 'Divya', 'Chloe', 'Jaques', 'Ishaan', 'Jackson','Deven','Kriti','Adam','Sean','Patrice','Rajeshwari','Varun','Avan','Salina','Artha','Barkha','Aditi','Shaan','Steve','Hugo','Dhoni','Joe','Arti','Mansi','Rekha','Hardik','Margot','Nicholas','Deepti','Dhruv','Shyla','Ajay','Jaya','Ravider','Aaron','Jimmy','Leo','Bharat','Amar','Ayush','Palpatine','David','Kane','Poonam','Anand','Shreya','Yashaswi','Dinesh','Rahul','Peter','Anjali','Ada','Glenn','Mitchell','Hiltion','Aristotle','Matt','Hillary','Anaka','Laxmi','Abhiman','Felix','Marcus','Alex','Pooja','Nikil','Diya','Harry','Virat','Louis','Nethra','Ambat','Agastya','kedar','Nathan','Amiya','Smriti','Shafali','Anuja','Nuzhat','Sahil','Rohit','Jason','Trump','Veda','Shikha','Pranav','Aisha','Kaeya','Taniya','Richa','Shivam','Harmanpreet','Jemimah','Michel','Arundhati','Radha','Ashton','Ishani','Shaila','Bumrah','Pat','Mattew','Ananya','Sana' ]
y = [5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12,12,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,25,25,25,26,26,27,28,28,28,30,30,0,0,0 ]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Students')
plt.ylabel('Marks')
plt.show()
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: by trend you mean fin line function? How you identify outliers, visual?

Comment: I would use the library numpy (it has a ton of good built in math functions). You can use numpy to identify outliers and a line of best fit or whatever you are looking for. Then you can change the color of those values or ignore them or do whatever you want in matplotlib. But matplotlib is meant for graphing more than actually doing calculations.